# Удаление записи из БД в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, база-данных, recyclerview

Есть `RecyclerView` вместе с `CardView`. На `CardView` выводятся записи из БД. По нажатию на элемент `CardView`, нужно чтобы удалялась запись из БД которая выведена на `CardView`. Вот функция с помощью которой я это делаю:

```
 public void deleteById(int id) {
    openDatabase();
    myDatabase.delete("table", String.valueOf(id), null);
    closeDatabase();
}
```

А вот Адаптер который выводит БД на `CardView`:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<RecyclerItem> listItems;
private Activity activity;
DialogFragment editDialog = new AlertDialogEdit();
DialogFragment deleteDialog = new AlertDialogDelete();
CallBackId callbackId;
RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(activity, listItems);
AlertDialogDelete alertDialogDelete = new AlertDialogDelete();

public RecyclerAdapter( Activity activity, List<RecyclerItem> listItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.listItems = listItems;

}

public void CallBackId(CallBackId callbackId){
    this.callbackId = callbackId;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Context context = holder.itemView.getContext();
    final int id = (listItems.get(position).getId());
    holder.txtTitle.setText(listItems.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.txtDescription.setText(listItems.get(position).getDescription());
    holder.txtOptionDigit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, holder.txtOptionDigit);
            popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.option_menu);
            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.mnu_item_edit:
                            editDialog.show(((AppCompatActivity)context).getFragmentManager(), "");
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Edited", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
                        case R.id.mnu_item_delete:     
          deleteDialog.show(((AppCompatActivity)context).getFragmentManager(), "");
                            listItems.remove(position);
                           recyclerAdapter.CallBackId(alertDialogDelete);
                            callbackId.collingBackId(id);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            popupMenu.show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listItems.size();
}
```

Нужно переменную `id` передать в класс где вызывается функция удаления. Попробовал сделать через `Callback`, так как с ними раньше не работал, нашел пример в интернете делал по нему вот что получилось, вот `Callback`:

```
public interface CallBackId {int collingBackId(int id);}
```

А вот функция в классе куда передается id:

```
@Override
public int collingBackId(int id) {
    return id;
}
```

Выдает следующие ошибки:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: mainProcess: 
com.example.user.project, PID: 3181
java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB

JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!

AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
```

Объясните пожалуйста что не так. И за ссылки на приличное и развернутое объяснение `Callback` тоже буду очень признателен.

Comment: Покажите код класса `RecyclerItem`.

Comment: Человек, посмотри мой код на гитхабе - https://github.com/ATumbler/Notepad/tree/master/app/src/main/java/ru/albatros/notepad

Comment: Коллега, вы пишете свое приложение, или решаете задачу из курса или учебника?

Comment: @tse, вы кому это?

Comment: Для начала если вы работате с SQLite, то адаптер должен работать с Cursor в качестве источника данных. Затем вы просто делаете свой колбэк из адаптера в активити, который передаст id из курсора.

Comment: @СергейГрушин в вашем коде лучше заменить прямые вызовы из адаптера в активити на колбэк.

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged не стоит использовать. Когда вы точно знаете, что удалили/добавили/изменили элемент, вызывайте соответствующие методы notifyItemXXX. При этом нельзя final'ить position. Если вам нужна позиция в обработчиках, используйте holder.getAdapterPosition(), иначе следующим этапом вы вызовете adapter.notifyItemDeleted(position), в колбэках остальных элементов так и останутся старые позиции, onBindViewHolder для них вызываться не будет при этом.

Comment: @pavlofff, спасибо! Исправлю

Comment: [Ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/625064/177345) про колбэк. Если этот ответ решит вашу проблему, то я на него закрою ваш вопрос, как дубликат.

Comment: @pavlofff Спасибо помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-поводу дискуссии в комментариях: на самом то деле тут все правы и одновременно неправы, поясню о чем идет речь.

- Дело в том, что если бы это был `ListView`, то действительно, как
  говорит @pavlofff достаточно было бы использовать `CursorAdapter` и в
  адаптере всегда был бы идентификатор записи, который можно
  использовать для удаления записи
- К счастью или к несчастью ТС использует `RecyclerView`, в коробочной поставке которого отсутствует `CursorAdapter`

Выхода 2:

1. Как заочно предполагает/предлагает @post_zeew воткнуть в `RecycleItem` идентификатор записи, так что всегда можно иметь его под рукой
2. Более правильный (ИМХО, конечно) способ использовать [CursorRecyclerViewAdapter](https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59) восполняющий отсутствующий в коробочной поставке `CursorAdapter` для `RecyclerView`

Comment: Для `RecyclerView` вообще отсутствуют готовые адаптеры, но нет ничего сложного передать в адаптер для `RecyclerView` курсор , в `onBindViewHolder()` получать из этого курора ID текущей позиции и передавать этот ID "наружу" через собственный колбэк - на реализацию уйдет пара минут и именно об этом я говорил в комментарии к вопросу. но можно конечно и уже готовые решения использовать, только предложенный вами не реализует колбэка, через `getItemId()` не всегда удобно получать ID/

Comment: А можно чуть конкретнее как правильно сделать Callback, раньше с таким не сталкивался. После поиска примеров сделал так создал интерфейс     public interface CallBackId { int collingBackId(int a);
}  Добавил в начало RecyclerAdapter. RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter =  new RecyclerAdapter(activity, listItems);
    AlertDialogDelete alertDialogDelete = new AlertDialogDelete();  и на кнопку delete повесил recyclerAdapter.CallBackId(alertDialogDelete);
                                callbackId.collingBackId(s);

Comment: в классе ответственном за диалог вызываю 
 public int collingBackId(int a) {  return a;}

Comment: Выбивает ошибку FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.user.project, PID: 3064
              java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB и FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION

Comment: @Binary оформите нормальный вопрос не в виде комментария