# Как правильно вызывать методы активности из адаптера?

Tags: android

Допустим у меня есть `RecyclerView`-адаптер и активность в разных файлах. Как мне правильно реализовать вызов методов в активности из адаптера? Пока реализовано так:

https://github.com/ATumbler/Notepad/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ru/albatros/notepad/NotesAdapter.java

Передаю контекст в адаптер, привожу его к классу активности и вызываю методы.

Слышал про колбэки, но не пойму никак что это и как это делать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Несколько необычная реализация предложена в другом ответе .. Напишу более класическое решение.

Для начала - что не так с вызовом методов активити из адаптера и почему это плохо. Дело в том, что активити - контреллер отображаемого на экране и именно она должна выступать в роли инициатора действий, расположенных на ней виджетов (адаптер это часть виджета для отображения списка). Если обратится к отвлеченному примеру, то при вызове из адаптера методов активити получается что то вроде того, что почтовый ящик "всасывает" квартиру с вами, чтобы вы смогли проверить почту, вместо того, чтобы вам идти туда посмотреть. Выглядит такое решение не очень.
Общий смысл в том, что управление должно инициировать действия, а не события воздействовать на управление (пульт управлять программами в телевизоре. а не программы переключать каналы)

Способы взаимодействия активити с адаптером зависят от типа взаимодействия - происходит ли событие в виджете (например, клик по элементу или в отвлеченном примере - пришла ли почта в ящик), на которое должно отреагировать активити или активити требуется какая-то информация\действие от виджета, например данные, отображаемые в виджете или обновление в списке.

В первом случае используется механизм колбэка (интерфейс обратного вызова). В отвлеченном примере мы установим в ящик датчик, коорый известит о наличии почты.
Данный механизм устроен так, что вызывая метод интерфейса в одном месте кода, он автоматически вызывается и в другом месте, которое реализует данный интерфейс  обратного вызова. При этом аргументы, полученные в методе-инициаторе связи, передаются в метод-получатель и вы можете передать данные, связанные с событием (например, ID записи).

Типичный колбэк.

В адаптере:

```
class SomeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <Data, SomeAdapter.ItemHolder> {


    // создаем сам интерфейс и указываем метод и передаваемые им аргументы
    // View на котором произошло событие и позиция этого View
    interface OnCardClickListener {
        void onCardClick(View view,  int position);
    }

    // создаем поле объекта-колбэка
    private static OnCardClickListener mListener;

    public SomeAdapter (Data data) {
     // конструктор адаптера
    }

    @Override
    public ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ....
        return new ItemHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder( ItemHolder holder, int position) {
        .....
    }

    // метод-сеттер для привязки колбэка к получателю событий
    public void setOnCardClickListener(OnCardClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public static class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        CardView mCard;

        public ItemHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            mCard = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.bell_card);
            // само событие, которое нужно передать (клик на элементе)
            mCard.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        // обработчик события
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // вызов метода-колбэка и назначение передаваемых значений аргументам
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            mListener.onCardClick(v, position);
        }
    }
}
```

В активити:

```
// имплементируем наш интерфейс обратного вызова в активити
public class SomeActiviy extends Activity implements SomeAdapter.OnCardClickListener {

    Data data;
    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mAdapter = new SomeAdapter(data);

        // подписываем нашу активити на события колбэка
        mAdapter.setOnCardClickListener(this);
        mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }


    // метод, который получит события из нашего колбэка
    @Override
    public void onCardClick(View view,final int pos) {

       // здесь обрабатываем событие, значения View и pos
       // равны значениям, присвоенным в адаптере
    }

}
```

Второй вариант гораздо проще, мы всего лишь создаем в адаптере методы, которые вернут нужные нам данные или вызовут определенные действия в адаптере, когда они потребуются активити. То есть, не адаптер вызывает методы активити, а активити вызывает методы адаптера, когда нуждается в информации/действиях от него:

в адаптере:

```
class SomeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <Data, SomeAdapter.ItemHolder> {

    // метод обновления списка по новому набору данных
    public void notifyData(Data result) {

        mData = result;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    // метод получения размера списка
    public int getSize() {
        return mData.size();
    }
}
```

В активити:

```
public class SomeActiviy extends Activity {

    Data data;
    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mAdapter = new SomeAdapter(data);
        mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // активити требуется размер списка
        int size = mAdapter.getSize();

        // активити требуется обновить список с вновь полученными данными
        Data data = getData();
        mAdapter.notifyData(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ваш ответ лучше :) Перенес галочку, спасибо, теперь вообще все понятно

Answer (score 3):

1) Внутри вашего класса NotesAdapter создаёте интерфейс и резервируете переменную.

```
 public class NotesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesAdapter.AdapterHolder>
    {

        public interface INotesAdapterCallback {
            void openEditor(String text, String color, long id, int position);
            void delete(long id);
        }


        INotesAdapterCallback callback;

        Cursor cursor;
        ...
    }
```

2) В вашей активности, добавьте имплементацию этого интерфейса

```
public class NotepadActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements INotesAdapterCallback
```

3) Сразу после этого, Студия предложит вам реализовать методы интерфейса (выделит заголовок красным, при нажатии на alt+enter предложит добавить методы). Сделайте это.

4. В адаптере, в конструктор передавайте не контекст (это утечка памяти), а экземпляр объекта, реализующего интерфейс.

   NotesAdapter(Cursor cursor, INotesAdapterCallback callback) {
           this.cursor = cursor;
           this.callback = callback;
       }
5. При работе с Холдером, обращайтесь к переменной **callback**

   public void onClick(View v) {
           if (callback != null) callback.openEditor(text, color, id, position);
       }
6. Вызов адаптера из активности теперь выглядит вот так:
   **notes_adapter = new NotesAdapter(cursor, this);**

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался

Comment: Спасибо, это работает у меня. И очень легко в использование))))