# Удаление выделенного элемента RecyclerView из бд

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-context-menu

Было приложение с `ListView`, переделываю его под `RecyclerView` c `CardView`. Раньше строки из списка удалялись через контекстное меню. Пробовал прикрутить контекстное меню к `RecyclerView` (для удаления) - не получилось... 
Сейчас пробую удалить через `LongClick`. Но если и получается удалить элемент то список не обновляется. Для чтения использую CursorLoader во фрагменте.

Подскажите как правильно организовать удаление ?

**RecordAdapter**

```
 public class RecordAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecordAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        Cursor dataCursor;
        Context context;

        public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public TextView date;
            public TextView distance;
            public ImageView imageView;
            public ViewHolder(View v) {
                super(v);

                date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
                distance = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
                imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivImg);

            }

        }


        public RecordAdapter(Activity mContext, Cursor cursor) {
            dataCursor = cursor;
            context = mContext;
        }

        @Override
        public RecordAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View cardview = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(cardview);
        }

        public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor cursor) {
            if (dataCursor == cursor) {
                return null;
            }
            Cursor oldCursor = dataCursor;
            this.dataCursor = cursor;
            if (cursor != null) {
                this.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            return oldCursor;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

            dataCursor.moveToPosition(position);

            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (dataCursor != null) {
                        dataCursor.moveToPosition(position);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Note.class);
                        long id = dataCursor.getLong(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(DB.COLUMN_ID));
                        intent.putExtra("id", id);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });

            holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());

                    builder.setTitle ("Удаление")
                            .setMessage ("Удалить ? "  )

                            .setNegativeButton("Отмена",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                }
                            })

                            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                                    // Тут хотел удалить элемент списка после чего нужно обновить список
                            dataCursor.moveToPosition(position);
                            long id = dataCursor.getLong(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(DB.COLUMN_ID));
                            DB notesDB = new DB(context);
                            notesDB.open();
                            notesDB.delRec(DB.DB_TABLE_NOTES, id);
                            notesDB.close();
                            notifyDataSetChanged();

                                }
                            });

                    builder.create().show();
                    return true;
                }
            });

            String date = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(DB.COLUMN_DATE));
            String title = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(DB.COLUMN_TITLE));
            String value = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(DB.COLUMN_COLOR));


            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyy");
            Date resultdate = new Date(Long.parseLong(date));
            String sdfDate = sdf.format(resultdate);


            if ( title.equals("")){
                title = context.getResources().getString(R.string.non_title);

            }

            holder.date.setText(sdfDate);
            holder.distance.setText(title);

            GradientDrawable bgShape = (GradientDrawable) holder.imageView.getBackground();
            bgShape.setColor( Integer.parseInt(value));


        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return super.getItemId(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return (dataCursor == null) ? 0 : dataCursor.getCount();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Лучше сделать удаление "смахиванием" элементов без всяких меню

Answer (score 0):

После удаления напиши : `notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Добавил в onClick удаление и notifyDataSetChanged();  но список не обновляется сразу. Может само удаление сделано не верно , или  notifyDataSetChanged(); не там поставил? (поправил код в вопросе, с внесенными изменениями )

Comment: @SergeyAlexandrov скорей всего, потому что данные считываются из dataCursor, а данные удаляются через notesDB. notifyDataSetChanged вызывается, но данные в курсоре не изменились. Скорей всего нужно вызвать уровнем выше swapCursor

Comment: Да, скорее всего в этом и была проблема. Но я нашел наверное более правильный метод удаления данных, нежели мой. Реализация через Callback.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/624618/245230
Теперь все работает как надо )