# Как вызвать метод kotlin активности из java адаптера android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Пытаюсь обновить данные в списке recyclerView который находится в активности. Проблема в чем для меня лично - активность на котлине а адаптер на джава. Если бы было все на джава, то там просто и понятно, а тут у меня возникли сложности. Пытался создать интерфейс и через него передавать данные в активность, но приложение падало раз за разом, в итоге эту идею забросил. Дальше пробовал сделать статическую функцию, вернее ее аналог `companion`. Создать то я создал, но из этой функции у меня нет доступа к переменным активности. В итоге я в тупике. В джава все было так:

1. в адаптере просто вызываем функцию активности:

   ```
    WriteResponseMess.deleteAttachment(position);
   ```
2. Ловим данные в активности и обновляем вьюху:

   ```
    public static void deleteAttachment(int adapterPosition) {
       mNames = adapter.getItems();
       mNames.remove(adapterPosition);
       adapter.updateNames(mNames);
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       mNames = adapter.getItems();
   }
   ```

все работало прекрасно. Видел [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/624575/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0) вопрос, пробовал сделать так как там написано, но не получилось. В итоге я не знаю как решить эту проблему. Надеюсь что она решается не так сложно как я представляю.

Comment: У Вас изначально код странный: адаптер вызывает метод активности, чтобы тот удалил позицию из самого же адаптера - это можно сделать не отходя от кассы. И вместо того чтобы передать ссылку на активность в адаптер и через неё обращаться к оной - Вы все методы и переменные сделали статическими, а это чревато утечками, потому как статические переменные живут дольше самой активности.

Comment: @woesss, как бы вам обьяснить что у меня происходит))) логика такая - я нажимаю на кнопку удаления item-a, дальше вызываю функцию которая удаляет из адаптера item по позиции (логика отсутствует я так понимаю) дальше мы обновляем адаптер, что собственно логичнее было бы сделать из самого адаптера, но при попытке удалить item у меня приложение падает с криками о том что индексы неверные и все в том же духе, чисто гипотетически можно рассмотреть вариант удаления из самого адаптера)

Comment: @woesss, и плюс проблема в том что по факту я удаляю item но он все-равно остается на своем месте, хотя его в адаптере нету уже

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как ни странно, вроде как удалось решить проблему через broadcastReceiver. Вот как я это сделал:

1. В адаптере вызываем наш `receiver` который находится в активности:

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setAction("item_position");
   intent.putExtra("position", position);
   context.sendBroadcast(intent);
   ```
2. В активности регистрируем `receiver` в функции `onCreate()`:

   ```
   val filter = IntentFilter("item_position")
       receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
           override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
               deleteAttachedItem(intent.extras.getInt("position"))
           }
       }
   ```

и дальше вызываем функцию для удаления item-a из списка.

### v. 2.0

придумал вариант, как удялить item из самого адаптера (спасибо [@woesss](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/11515/woesss)). Вот как обрабатывается клик по кнопке удалить в самом item-e:

```
holder.deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(view -> {

                array = MySingleton.getInstance().getArray();
                if (array.size() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
                        JsonObject object = array.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                        if (object.get("filename").toString().substring(1, object.get("filename").toString().length() - 1).equals(mNames.get(position))) {
                            array.remove(object);
                            mNames.remove(position);
                            MySingleton.getInstance().setArray(array); // удаляем запись из источника (как я понял)
                            updateNames(mNames);
                        }

                    }
                }

        });
```

и вот функция для обновления данных в самом адаптере:

```
public void updateNames(ArrayList<String> names) {
        mNames = names;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: хоть вы и добавили вариант решения. я подозреваю оно не оптимальное. Поделитесь подробностями что именно не так. Какую ошибку выдавало приложение при падении? Я постоянно использую в одном проекте и java, и kotlin, и никаких особых проблем никогда не испытывал

Comment: что было не так? ну хотя-бы то, что я не имел доступа к методу активности, и как результат не мог никак повлиять на отображение вьюхи, а это решение вроде бы решило мои проблемы, или вы считаете что есть что-то более изящное для решения данной задачи ? :)

Comment: По поводу статических функций, в Kotlin они делаются намного проще чем в java, вы просто вне класса создаёте функцию и можете получить к ней доступ с любой точки вашего приложения. Также вы можете и создавать и статические переменные.

Comment: Я считаю, что фраза "не имел доступа к методу" немного неполна) Компилятор не дает вам вызвать статическую java функцию из котлин-класса? Какая ошибка выпадала, когда вы пытались передавать интерфейсы? Вы говорите "ничего не получается", но не говорите что вы делаете

Comment: По поводу интерфейсов не согласен, ищите проблему у себя, у меня интерфейсы работают без проблем. Не забывайте что переменные приходящие из джава классов компилятор не в состоянии проверить на null. Потому все приходящие данные нужно проверять самому хоть и компилятор об этом не говорит. P.S. Я вам говорил уже о книге: Kotlin в действии. Эту мелочь нужно знать о взаимодействии java и kotlin классов

Comment: @СпицкоДмитрий, `не имел доступа к методу` - это значит что из адаптера я не вижу метода для обновления вьюхи, в вопросе я привел вариант из джава, так вот если пытаться получить доступ из джава адаптера к методу джава активности, то я его вижу и могу передать данные

Comment: А по поводу решения с броадкастом - оно, конечно, работает, но представьте себе ситуацию: квартира, в которой окна в разных комнатах выходят на разные стороны дома. Два человека сидят в этой квартире в разных комнатах, и чтобы общаться открывают окна и орут на всю ивановскую "Вася, хочешь чаю". Да, работает. Но все зрители происходящего в легком недоумении :)

Comment: @Valeriy, я пробовал интерфейс сделать, не получилось, не исключен вариант что я не правильно делал, если есть рабочий вариант, то буду благодарен если поделитесь, статическую функцию я сделал в активности, в итоге я не вижу переменных которые есть в активности, и на этом идея померла

Comment: Вы опять говорите что не работает, но не говорите что вы делаете и как определяете, что это не работает. Я прямо сейчас перепроверил - видимость статических функций из котлина не требует никаких лишних телодвижений, значит что-то не так у вас. А что именно мы не сможем сказать, пока вы не дадите более конкретной информации

Comment: @СпицкоДмитрий, у меня изначально было желание сделать через статический метод, в итоге не получилось, может из-за недостатка практики в котлине, дальше я пробовал сделать через интерфейс, тоже не получилось, в итоге получилось только через ресивер, согласен что не идеально, но по-другому не получилось

Comment: @СпицкоДмитрий, что я делаю: создал в активности(котлин) метод в companion object но когда я попытался получить доступ к переменным активности то я их не увидел, хотя они были var, в итоге забросил идею, мне же нужно менять переменные которые висят в активности, например массив названий item-ов для того же списка, а я этот массив не вижу из функции

Comment: Таки активность на котлине, а адаптер на джаве? Потому что приведенный в вопросе код говорит об обратной ситуации. В общем, не дополните вопрос адекватными подробностями - не вижу смысла продоолжать беседу. Фраза "попробовал - не получилось" не является подробностями. Не имеет значение что вы там пробовали, имеет значение как вы поняли, что это не работает

Comment: @СпицкоДмитрий, я же там написал что на чем написано, так же добавил код того что было, когда и активность и адаптер были на джава :)